# google_maps_api.xml not created in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-maps

I am trying to create a google map activity in android studio, but the file `google_maps_api.xml` was not created in the `res/values folder` (see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYq7k.png)). Am I missing something or can I just create the file myself?

o I tried to research why this might happen, but I was unable to determine why `google_maps_api.xml` would not be created automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio underwent some modifications a while back and stopped creating the google_maps_api.xml file automatically. You need to do two things instead:

1. Open the project's local.properties file and add the line `MAPS_API_KEY=YOUR_KEY_HERE`, replacing YOUR_KEY_HERE with your API key.
2. Open AndroidManifest.xml file and replace YOUR_API_KEY with `${MAPS_API_KEY}` as shown below.

```
<application ...>

       <meta-data
           android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
           android:value="${MAPS_API_KEY}" />
       
       <activity ...>
          ...
       </activity>
   </application>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that `google_maps_api.xml` is just a file with some resources such as strings or integers. So you can just manually add it by yourself in the `res/values` folder in your module. And after that add any resources (API keys or something else) in this file.

Comment: yeah after testing it, it was just a file I could add by myself. I was just worried that maybe I need to install something else